# Reachability error in integration of admob

Tags: iphone, ios, admob

I am trying to integrate admob in my ios application but I am getting following errors when I add sdk and build it.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker startNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[GADNetworkChecker stopNetworkChecking] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNetworkChecker.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have included all required framework including SystemConfiguration, CFNetwork etc.

### Update

I am getting this error when I build in simulator but not when I build with device. is it sdk issue? I am using simulator 5.1.

Comment: Looks like you're using GoogleAdMob. Have you added the GoogleAd SDK? I believe you have to get the GoogleAd SDK separately and add it in you project.

Comment: yes i have added GoogleAdmobSdk but havent seen a different GoogleAd sdk

Comment: Have you checked your Build Phases and made sure that the GoogleAdMob SDK is properly added on the project?

Comment: yes it is present under build phases. The app works on device but fails on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the frameworks that you added are correctly linked under the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of your Build Settings. Also, look at "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases" to make sure all of the relevant files you want to compile are there.